# Splitting a string on the page

Tags: c#, algorithm

Is it possible to split a continuous text on a page? A4 page format. I'll never do it. Need advice. Thank you!

//
The only thing that comes to mind is to take a page size A4, continue to calculate the size of each row. In C # use TextRenderer.MeasureText.

Comment: `"I'll never do it.  Need advice."`

Comment: why should you need advice if you never do it? are you trying to print?

Comment: I guess he's trying to say : `I've never done it. Need advice.` stop breaking his balls :)

Comment: It's not very clear what you're actually asking. Are you asking about printing (to a real printer, on a real paper page), or do you want to break the text yourself ?

Comment: simple suggestion (removing lot of if..s): To screen `TextRenderer.MeasureText` To printer `Graphics.MeasureString`

Answer (score 0):

This is the code i am using to perform word-wrap in XNA. Just convert the `SpriteFont.MeasureString` calls to whatever is appropriate for you. Note that there COULD still be bugs in here and its pretty mind bending to debug.

```
/// <summary>
/// Extensions to SpriteFont.
/// </summary>
public static class SpriteFontExtensions
{      
    /// <summary>
    /// Abstractly represents a substring by its start index and length.
    /// </summary>
    public struct SubString
    {
        public int StartIndex;
        public int Length;
    }

    private static List<SubString> _lines = new List<SubString>();

    /// <summary>
    /// Wraps a string into sub-string lines, each line no longer (in pixels) than the specified lineWidth.
    /// 
    /// JCF: This is a conversion of Torque3D's GFont::wrapString, available on GitHub. 
    /// </summary>
    public static void WrapString(this SpriteFont font, string inText, int lineWidth, int hangingIndentWidth, List<SubString> outLines)
    {
        // Early out, no text passed to us.
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(inText))
            return;

        var strb = new StringBuilder(inText);
        WrapString(font, strb, lineWidth, hangingIndentWidth, outLines);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Wraps a string into sub-string lines, each line no longer (in pixels) than the specified lineWidth.
    /// 
    /// JCF: This is a conversion of Torque3D's GFont::wrapString, available on GitHub
    /// </summary>
    public static void WrapString(this SpriteFont font, StringBuilder strb, int lineWidth, int hangingIndentWidth, List<SubString> outLines)
    {
        if (strb.Length == 0)
            return;

        var firstLetterWidth = font.MeasureString(strb[0].ToString()).X;

        // Early out, not even the first letter will fit within the lineWidth available.
        if (firstLetterWidth > lineWidth)
            return;

        var len = strb.Length;
        var startLine = 0;

        for (var i = 0; i < len;)
        {
            startLine = i;

            // loop until the string is too large
            var needsNewLine = false;
            var lineStrWidth = 0;
            for (; i < len; i++)
            {
                if (strb[i] == '\n')
                {
                    needsNewLine = true;
                    break;
                }

                var subStr = strb.Substring(startLine, (i - startLine) + 1);
                lineStrWidth = (int) (font.MeasureString(subStr).X);
                if (outLines.Count > 0)
                    lineStrWidth += hangingIndentWidth;

                if (lineStrWidth > lineWidth)
                {
                    needsNewLine = true;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (!needsNewLine)
            {
                // we are done!
                var line = new SubString()
                               {
                                   StartIndex = startLine,
                                   Length = i - startLine,
                               };
                outLines.Add(line);
                return;
            }

            var j = 0;

            // Did we hit a hardwrap (newline character) in the string.
            bool hardwrap = (strb[i] == '\n');

            if (hardwrap)
            {
                j = i;
            }
                // determine where to put the newline
                // we need to backtrack until we find a space character 
                // we don't do this for hardwrap(s)
            else
            {
                for (j = i - 1; j >= startLine; j--)
                {
                    if (char.IsSeparator(strb[j]))
                        break;
                }

                if (j < startLine)
                {
                    // the line consists of a single word!              
                    // So, just break up the word

                    j = i - 1;
                }
            }

            // 
            {
                var line = new SubString()
                    {
                        StartIndex = startLine,
                        Length = j - startLine + 1,
                    };
                outLines.Add(line);

                i = line.StartIndex + line.Length;
            }

            // Now we need to increment through any space characters at the
            // beginning of the next line.
            // We don't skip spaces after a hardwrap because they were obviously intended.                
            for (; i < len; i++)
            {
                if (strb[i] == '\n')
                    continue;

                if (char.IsSeparator(strb[i]) && !hardwrap)
                    continue;

                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}